# Spring Boot JPA with MySQL - cannot create controller bean due to dependency issue

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm working through various aspects of Spring Boot in the last few days and today I've been frustrated by JpaRepository. [The example is introductory](https://hevodata.com/learn/spring-boot-mysql/), MySQL + JPA, built around the MVC design. I've a previous MySQL integration with Core Java, but not Spring Boot.

The code is as follows:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fanshawe</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-mysql-jpa-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-mysql-jpa-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot, Maven, Spring JPA and MySQL</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

BlogRepo.java:

```
package com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
//to import quickly, click Ctrl-Shift-O
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog;

@Repository
public interface BlogRepo extends JpaRepository<Blog, Integer>{
    
    List<Blog> findByTitleContainingOrContentContaining(String text, String textAgain);

    Blog findOne(int blogId);

}
```

Blog.java:

```
package com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Blog {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    private String title;
    private String content;
    
    public Blog() {
    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public Blog(String title, String content) {
        
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setContent(content);
    }
    
    public Blog(int id, String title, String content) {
    
        this.setId(id);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setContent(content);
    }
    
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Blog [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", content=" + content + "]";
    }

}
```

BlogController.java:

```
package com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog;
import com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo;

@RestController
public class BlogController {
    
    @Autowired
    BlogRepo blogRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public List<Blog> displayAllBlogs() {
        return blogRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public Blog show(@PathVariable String id) {
        
        int blogId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        
        return blogRepo.findOne(blogId);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/blog/search")
    public List<Blog> searchBlogs(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String searchTerm = body.get("text");
        return blogRepo.findByTitleContainingOrContentContaining(searchTerm, searchTerm);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/blog")
    public Blog create(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        
        String title = body.get("title");
        String content = body.get("content");
        
        return blogRepo.save(new Blog(title, content));
        
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public Blog update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        
        int blogId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        
        Blog blog = blogRepo.findOne(blogId);
        
        blog.setTitle(body.get("title"));
        blog.setContent(body.get("content"));
        
        return blogRepo.save(blog);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public boolean delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        
        int blogId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        
        blogRepo.deleteById(blogId);
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the main app file:

```
package com.example.springbootmysqljpademo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SpringbootMysqlJpaDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootMysqlJpaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties for the mysql configuration:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The stack trace:

> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'blogController': Unsatisfied dependency
> ```
>
> expressed through field 'blogRepo'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'blogRepo' defined in
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringbootMysqlJpaDemoApplication:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int); Reason:
> Failed to create query for method public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method
> public abstract com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.SpringbootMysqlJpaDemoApplication.main(SpringbootMysqlJpaDemoApplication.java:14)
> ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'blogRepo' defined in
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpringbootMysqlJpaDemoApplication:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int); Reason:
> Failed to create query for method public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method
> public abstract com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> ... 25 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int); Reason:
> Failed to create query for method public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method
> public abstract com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1052)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> ... 35 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.model.Blog
> com.example.springbootmysqljpademo.repo.BlogRepo.findOne(int)! No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:119)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:259)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> ... 57 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property 'findOne' found for type 'Blog'
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:91)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:438)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:414)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:367)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
> ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:349)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:332)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:81)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:251)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:384)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:385)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:93)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
> ... 61 common frames omitted

This is what I've tried to resolve it:

1. Changed the table name in the MySQL table to match the rest
2. Fields, Column names, are all aligned.
3. Added @ComponentScan to the main class - I think I don't think to further concretize it in its parameters. The base package would be the main class, no?
4. Added @EnableJpaRepositories to the main class, as well.
5. Checked dependencies - added **javax.api**, which is a top solution that had no effect.
6. **my-sql-connector-j**, is a recent innovation vis-a-vis the version used in the example.
7. One change against the original is `Blog findOne(int blogId);`, because the code had a problem using `findById` vs. `findOne` methods, so I had to do it this way to use the `findOne` method.
8. `@Controller` needs to be `@RestController` to compile properly.
9. I do have the `@Repository` annotation atop the respective class.
10. The project was not organized in packages originally, but I've made that adjustment.
11. No slashes missing in any of the mapping...
12. I don't think a service component is necessary, per se? It outsources the methods in the controller, from which they will be invoked anyway.
13. Checked out these links:

[Unsatisfied dependency exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name)

[JPA Crud Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254157/spring-boot-jpa-crudrepository)

[Spring cannot create bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611087/spring-cannot-create-bean)

Beyond this, I'm suspecting that it's an issue with the way I've done the annotations, though nothing stands out at me after reading through various sources, even if I don't have the most sophisticated understanding of them. At this point, I'm at a general loss how to approach it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this answer and see if it helps. You should not be using `findOne` instead use `findById` I see that you already tried it and post whatever problem you faced with it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370947/460557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with component scan you are supposed to add base package too, before doing that try out putting em all in one package that would tell you if its an issue with packaging. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-unsatisfied-dependency, this link covers reason for UnsatisfiedDependencyException, check it out if you haven't.

Edit: You don't need to enable component scan, that is handled by @SprintBootApplication itself
source: [image: screengrab from spring.io]https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html